# how to create a date range mapping in spark?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with following structure.

```
+-------+-------------------+
|country|     date_published|
+-------+-------------------+
|     UK|2020-04-15 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-04-14 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-04-09 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-04-08 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-04-07 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-04-06 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-04-03 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-04-02 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-04-01 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-31 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-30 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-27 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-26 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-25 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-24 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-23 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-20 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-19 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-18 00:00:00|
|     UK|2020-03-17 00:00:00|
+-------+-------------------+
```

I want to create a date mapping based on this data. Conditions,

1. All dates till 2020-01-01 should be mapped as "YTD".
2. All dates till 2019-04-15 should be mapped as "LAST_1_YEAR".
3. All dates from 2019-01-01 till 2019-04-15(last year date as of day) should be mapped as "YTD_LAST_YEAR"
4. All dates before 2019-04-15 should be mapped as "YEAR_AGO_1_YEAR"
5. We can create two columns like ytd_map(condition 1, 3), last_year_map(condition 2,4)

**There could be other countries in the list, and the above conditions should work for them**

Approach I tried, is to create a dataframe with max_date_published for each country, but I not sure how to filter the dataframe for each country separately.

```
df_data = df_data_cleaned.select("date_published","country").distinct().orderBy(F.desc("date_published"))
df_max_dt = df_data.groupBy("country").agg(F.max(F.col("date_published")))
df_max_dt.collect()
```

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried..?

Comment: I have tried creating a data frame with max_date for each country then filter it accordingly, but presence of multiple countries in the dataset making it complicated.

Comment: @anidev711 why are you grouping it though? You just need the dates to be mapped to different buckets, right?

Comment: ya, rather than grouping it would be right to say different partitions. Solved it using sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and working as of now.

```
spark.sql("select country,\
    date_published,\
    (case when date_published >= max_date_published_last_year then 'LAST_1_YEAR'\
     when date_published <= max_date_published_last_year and date_published >= add_months(max_date_published_last_year, -12) then  'YEAR_AGO_1_YEAR' else '' end) as MAT_MAPPING,\
     (case when date_published >= date_published_start_of_year then 'YTD'\
     when date_published <= max_date_published_last_year and date_published >= date_published_start_of_last_year\
     then 'YTD_LAST_YEAR'\
              else '' end) as YTD_MAPPING from\
    (select t.country, t.date_published, t.date_published_ya, t.max_date_published_current_year,\
    cast(add_months(t.max_date_published_current_year, -12) as timestamp) as max_date_published_last_year,\
          date_trunc('year', max_date_published_current_year) AS date_published_start_of_year,\
          date_trunc('year', cast(add_months(t.max_date_published_current_year, -12) as timestamp)) AS date_published_start_of_last_year\
          from\
    (select country,\
    date_published,cast(add_months(date_published, -12) as timestamp) as date_published_ya,\
    max(date_published)over(partition by country order by date_published desc) max_date_published_current_year from df_mintel_time) t) t2")
```